# Mysql Left Join DataTable Serverside Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatable, left-join

Can you help me on this?

> No tables used
>
> SELECT * ORDER BY `id` asc LIMIT 0

This is my sql code on the model

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{
    
    $this->db->query("SELECT mainproduk.id,
    mainproduk.barcode as barcod,
    mainproduk.nama_produk,
    mainproduk.nama_alias,
    mainproduk.satuan,
    mainproduk.produk_jadi,
    mainproduk.kemasan,
    mainproduk.min_stok_kemasan,
    mainproduk.status,
    mainproduk.top_item,
    mainproduk.tipe_produk,
    mainproduk.nomor_kemtan,
    coalesce(sum(R.jumlah_pc),0) as omzet
    FROM mainproduk
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT id,barcode, jumlah_pc
        FROM rincian_order WHERE tipe='po' AND status!='canceled' AND tanggal_kirim BETWEEN '$kemarins' AND '$blnkemarin'
    ) AS R
        ON mainproduk.barcode = R.barcode WHERE status=1 GROUP BY mainproduk.id ORDER BY mainproduk.id ASC");


    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
            
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```

When I use the above method will appear no table problem is used, because the recording is off.

then I change it with the active record like below and there is an error that seems "COALESCE" does not support in such format, then if "coalesce (sum (details_order.jumlah_pc), 0) as omzet" I delete it will appear error as below this

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->select('mainproduk.barcode as barcod, mainproduk.nama_produk, mainproduk.nama_alias, mainproduk.satuan, mainproduk.produk_jadi, mainproduk.kemasan, mainproduk.min_stok_kemasan, mainproduk.status, mainproduk.top_item, mainproduk.tipe_produk, mainproduk.nomor_kemtan, coalesce(sum(rincian_order.jumlah_pc),0) as omzet')
        ->from('mainproduk')
        ->join('rincian_order', 'mainproduk.barcode = rincian_order.barcode', 'left')
        ->where('mainproduk.status =', 1)
        ->group_by('mainproduk.id')
        ->order_by('mainproduk.id', 'ASC');     

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
            
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```

> Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

Please help

Comment: I can't see any ambiguity here

Comment: my problem was solved, but there was another problem I was facing, and I asked again with a new question

Answer (score 0):

```
`mainproduk.id` 
`mainproduk.barcode`
```

similarly to other fields
try writing this as your syntax.

if that doesn't work can you print_r the query ?

Comment: my problem was solved, but there was another problem I was facing, and I asked again with a new question